# React - change image on click - refactoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

so in my app I've got 6 divs with the same images that I'm changing on click, but it only works with 6 different functions (as below), I know that it can be done with one function in which I'm passing props to different divs, but I cant get it working, when i do it 1 div click changes images for all of the others. That's why I did it with 6 different state elements. Can any one guide me how to achieve this without replicating the functions?

here are functions

```
   toggleImage = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ open: !state.open }));
  };
  toggleImage2 = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ open2: !state.open2 }));
  };
  toggleImage3 = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ open3: !state.open3 }));
  };




  getImageName = () => (this.state.open ? dumbell : dumbellgrey);
  getImageNameTic = () => (this.state.open ? checkImg : "");

  getImageName2 = () => (this.state.open2 ? dumbell2 : dumbellgrey2);
  getImageNameTic2 = () => (this.state.open2 ? checkImg2 : "");

  getImageName3 = () => (this.state.open3 ? dumbell3 : dumbellgrey3);
  getImageNameTic3 = () => (this.state.open3 ? checkImg3 : "");
```

and thats what I'm rendering

````
<div onClick={this.toggleImage} id={1}>
        <ImageBox>
            <DumbellImg src={imageName}></DumbellImg>
            <TickImg src={ticName}></TickImg>
        </ImageBox>
    </div>
    <div onClick={this.toggleImage2} id={1}>
        <ImageBox>
            <DumbellImg src={imageName}></DumbellImg>
            <TickImg src={ticName}></TickImg>
        </ImageBox>
    </div>
    <div onClick={this.toggleImage3} id={1}>
        <ImageBox>
            <DumbellImg src={imageName}></DumbellImg>
            <TickImg src={ticName}></TickImg>
        </ImageBox>
    </div>
``` etc.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image id as a function argument to a common toggleImage function.

```
<div onClick={()=>toggleImage(1)} id={1}>
              <ImageBox>
                <DumbellImg src={imageName}></DumbellImg>
                <TickImg src={ticName}></TickImg>
              </ImageBox>
</div>
```

Then,In toggleImage Function set the state:

```
toggleImage = (id) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ ["open" + id]: !state["open" + id] }));
};
```

Comment: I cant get this to work, in this case, should I also add id to state ?

Comment: Have been trying to get this to work for past 2 hours, do I need to also change anything in "getImageName" and "getImageNameTic" functions or not ? toogleImage is not modifying state for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like @subransu said but I think it's always easier to just create a new custom component, i.e an ImageToggle component:

```js
const ImageToggle = () => {
  const [showImage, toggleImage] = useState(false);

  return showImage && (
    <div onClick={() => toggleImage(true)}>
        <ImageBox>
            <DumbellImg src={imageName}></DumbellImg>
            <TickImg src={ticName}></TickImg>
        </ImageBox>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way you do not need to keep track of a more complicated key/value map as each custom component has it's own state.

Comment: thank you for the tip, what does 'useState(false)' do in this case?

Comment: Also, where does the state come from in that case? should i create a state in that componanet with open:true or ?

Comment: useState is same as setState, it's just newer as it's a react hook.

State comes from it, read up on react hooks and set states.

I would recommend trying this way as it's easier than id key/value way